# Notation in surgery theory (maths)

Tags: geometry, differential-topology, surgery-theory

[sary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEQK5.png)

Hello everyone! In reading an article on surgery theory I found an expression of the type $M \cup_{\phi} N $ where $M$ and $N$ are manifolds(or more generally topological spaces), and $\phi$ some fixed function. Could you explain more about this notation ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: my question is not about how to edit symbols, it is about the meaning of the symbol $\cup_{\phi}$ where $\phi$ is a function.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that you should type your question, instead of posting an image.

Comment: okay, I have typed the question

Comment: Notation depends enough on context that its hard to answer your question. If you give more context to the question it may be easier. Sometimes the notation you describe denotes the pushout, but that wouldn't make sense here unless there are other conditions on $M$, $N$ and $\phi$

Comment: Actually the article says the following: for a manifold $M$ of dimension $n = p+ q + 1$, $\phi: S^q \times D^q  \rightarrow M$ an embedding, we define M' to be $(M\setminus int(im(\phi))) \cup_{\phi_{S^p\times S^{q-1}}} (D^{p+1}\times S^{q-1})$ .  Anyway, your answer has helped me. Thank you.

Comment: It's just telling you what the gluing map is (also called attaching map). Every topological quotient needs one, since we need to know how things get identified.